# TNS Listener -ORA-12514 error following database shutdown - Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g, ora-12514

I have hit a problem with my oracle development database.

When in sqlplus I executed the shutdown command, but nothing happened for several minutes and it was just hanging. No messages were displayed to the screen. The only thing was to close the command window. When I open sqlplus again and enter in the user name password as sysdba I am getting ORA 12514 TNS Listener could not resolve service in descriptor. This is odd as I could log on before and use the database. So I thought that the services were still shutting down I waited, and using the Windows snap on tool for Oracle 11g, I restarted the services on the database, but this has had no effect.

Even using EM made no difference because I couldn't log on to perform a startup or recovery.

So, please does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: issue shutdown abort; or shutdown immediate;

Comment: Does this terminate any session or service that may be running, and allow me to log back on normally? How do I get back on to execute shutdown abort if it is not letting me log in?

Comment: yes, `shutdown abort` terminates everything. set the ORACLE_SID,ORACLE_HOME env vars correctly then issue `sqlplus /nolog` then `conn sys/pwd as sysdba;` then `startup` this will mount open and start db. then check your listeners

Comment: Can ask about the process of logging on. Are you describing as open sqlplus with user as system/pwd as sysdba; shutdown abort; startup; ?

Comment: not `system` but `sys` and first setup your ORACLE_ variables. then `sqlplus /nolog` from commandline. then issue `conn sys/yourpassword as sysdba; shutdown abort;` .. wait abit till it shutsdown. then `startup`

Comment: Just to let you know that your advice worked! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

May need to startup the listener:  `lsnrctl start`

See:  http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/05/oracle-lsnrctl-listener-shutdown-and-startup-procedures/

Comment: This is only referring to Linux, I am on a windows server 2003 box

Comment: Yes, because the database was working normally before and none of the variables have changed. I have tried to understand why this has happened, and my thought is swaying towards the fact that I did a normal shutdown, which I understand can take hours

Comment: rephrasing comment. there's a LSNRCTL utility in windows in the ORACLE_HOME/bin directory which is working as service too. it can be used to check the listener status/startup the listeners are described in the `ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/listener.ora` file.

Answer (score -1):

Kindly check your TNS listener that is it working properly .

You can also check in (computer--> manage-) change the tns listener to automatic , you may not get problem.

If you still getting problem then there might be a change in your database.